# Is there any function to index the result of a computation on a collection?

Tags: clojure

Sincere apologies if this has been answered before. The search terms I came up with for this one weren't really specific...

I have defined the following function in a utils namespace, but it seems rather silly and is probably defined somewhere else:

```
(defn index-with
  "returns a map of x -> (f x) for every x in xs"
  [f xs]
  (apply hash-map (mapcat #(vector % (f %)) xs)))
```

Here's an example of its usage:

```
(index-with count ["a" "bb" "ccc" "ddd"])
=> {"a" 1, "bb" 2, "ccc" 3, "ddd" 3}
```

If you were to invert the roles of keys and values (potentially ambiguous), you'd get something like `group-by`'s output:

```
(group-by count ["a" "bb" "ccc" "ddd"])
=> {1: ["a"], 2: ["bb"], 3: ["ccc", "ddd"]}
```

I also looked at `clojure.set/index` but it seems to only cover a specific scenario (which doesn't apply here).

Does something like this exist already in the Clojure core-lib?

Comment: "a map of `x -> (f x)`" is just "an implementation of `f`, no? Is this for purposes of caching an expensive function?

Comment: @Magos: you can look at it as a cache for some expensive computation. In my case though, the xs don't span the whole domain of f, so the resulting map is only a subset of the implementation. It is a convenient way to inspect the output for many inputs at once, the computational cost is not really a worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `clojure.core/zipmap` is reasonably close to what I am looking for:

```
(def xs ["a" "bb" "ccc" "ddd"])
(zipmap xs (map count xs))
=> {"a" 1, "bb" 2, "ccc" 3, "ddd" 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have proposed two one line implementations.  A third might be:

```
(into {} (map (juxt identity count)) xs)
```

All three of **solutions appear to assume uniqueness** in the `xs` input.  If you have a seperate function then I'd expect it should deal with the collisions in a reasonable way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to accumulate a look-aside table of a pure function, then the function you want is [`memoize`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize).

> The memoized version of the function keeps a cache of the mapping from
>   arguments to results ...